# iOS, NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

I had a problem in my project where I declared in the header file an NSMutableDictionary property like so:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *DataDict ;
```

Now in the implementation file, I go ahead and initialise this dictionary because I am gonna use it, like so:

```
DataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

Now when I did this, the minute I try to add something to this dictionary I would get this error message:

> -[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x885ae60 2012-10-19 16:51:56.040 testing[2297:c07] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI
>   setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x885ae60'

After a while and running through my project a thousand times, I decided to uncomment my initialization line, like so

```
 //DataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

and that fixed the problem.

My question is: Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is in the way you have defined your property. If you change it to:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *DataDict ;
```

instead of `copy` everything should be fine.

This happens because you basically say that you want a copy of your object through your generated accessors, which returns an `NSDictionary` instead (an immutable copy).

You can find more on [objective-c properties here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).

Just as a sidenote: objective-c ivars usually start with a lowercase letter (uppercase names are used for classes), so `dataDict` should be preferred over `DataDict`.

Comment: Does that mean I should make the reference strong, and then alloc init? or make it strong and no need to alloc init?

Comment: By making it `strong` you just saying that you want to keep a strong relationship (owning) with that object (which basically means that you want it to be deallocated when the owner deallocates). You still have to alloc/init the object as always.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the property have "copy" attribute so NSMutableDictionary instance alloc/init-ed is "copy"'ed using "copy" method, and "copy" method create not NSMutableDictionary but NSDictionary. ("mutableCopy" will create NSMutableDictionary).

Probably, you can use "retain" instead of "copy" as attributes.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *DataDict ;
```

Or, just without "copy"/"retain" but use ARC.(Automatic reference counting).

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact problem.  No combination of retain/copy/strong/weak, etc do the trick.  What does work is to create a temporary  Mutable Dictionary, load it up and then set my original equal to it.

```
 NSMutableDictionary * tempD = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[tempD setObject: epsTapeCut forKey:LWPrintParameterKeyTapeCut];
[tempD setObject: epsCopies forKey:LWPrintParameterKeyCopies];
[tempD setObject: epsHalfCut forKey:LWPrintParameterKeyHalfCut];
[tempD setObject: epsPrintSpeed forKey:LWPrintParameterKeyPrintSpeed];
[tempD setObject: epsDensity forKey:LWPrintParameterKeyTapeWidth];

self.ePSprintSettings = tempD;
```

This fails:

```
 [self.ePSprintSettings setObject: epsTapeCut forKey:LWPrintParameterKeyTapeCut];
```

Declaration:

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *ePSprintSettings;
```

(But again, no combination of attributes makes a difference.)

Initialization:

```
 self.ePSprintSettings = (NSMutableDictionary *)[myUserDefaults dictionaryForKey:kEpsPrintSettings];
```

Thank you for helping me understand.

I'm happy enough that this works, but I'd like to understand why.